# hide parent div based on partial name id of child

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I wish to hide the parent div class "field" when his child is a textarea

```js
var child = document.querySelector('[id^=booked-textarea-paragraph-text-]').id;
var parent = child.parents('div');

console.log(child);
console.log(parent);
```

```html
<div class="field">
<label class="field-label">Remarque éventuelle :</label>
<br/>
<textarea id="booked-textarea-paragraph-text-label---3501121" data-calendar-id="19" name="paragraph-text-label---3501121"></textarea>
</div>
```

You can check on this jsfiddle =>
http://jsfiddle.net/zc1orbp8/

Comment: there is no parent `li` element. Please provide it in the question so the snipped might work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your JS code seems rather confused. For example, `this` will be a reference to the `window`, not any specific element as it seems to expect. Also, `child` will be a string, so calling `parents()` on it will not work.

If you're happy to use jQuery, then you can solve this in one line using `:has` to select the element which has a `textarea` child, and `hide()`.

```js
$('.field:has(textarea)').hide();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="field">
  <label class="field-label">Remarque éventuelle :</label><br/>
  <textarea id="booked-textarea-paragraph-text-label---3501121" data-calendar-id="19" name="paragraph-text-label---3501121"></textarea>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
$("textarea[name='paragraph-text-label---3501121']").closest("div.field").css("display", "none"); // it is not good practice to use name like this. "paragraph-3501121" this could be better one
```

Answer (score 0):

Whit plain javascript you may use something like this, try it and see if it can help you

```
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"> 
 </script>

 <div class="field">
    <label class="field-label">Remarque éventuelle :</label><br/>
    <textarea id="booked-textarea-paragraph-text-label---3501121" data-calendar- 
     id="19" name="paragraph-text-label---3501121"></textarea>
    <br>
    <button id="button">Hide this</button>
 </div>
 <script type="text/javascript">
   let child    =document.getElementById("booked-textarea-paragraph-text-label-- 
   -3501121");
    let parent  =child.parentNode;
    let button =document.getElementById("button");
    button.addEventListener("click",function({
       parent.style.display ="none";
    })
 </script>
```